# How to analyze matched case-control data in spss

Tags: spss

I am using SPSS 22 for Mac.

I have a dataset in which one of the variables is the id of the matched control for that case.

The data looks kinda like this:

```
id         case     animal       fruit        matched control    outcome
___________________________________________________________________________
1          yes      horse        apple         4                 died
2          no       elefant      orange                          survived
3          yes      horse        banana        5                 survived
4          no       horse        apple                           died
5          no       shark        apple                           died
```

Where case 1 (horse, apple) is matched with control 4 (horse, apple)
and case 3 (horse, banana) id matched with control 5 (shark, apple)
and control 2 should be excluded from the analysis because it is not referenced by any case.

I would like to:

1. create a table with baseline characteristics of cases and controls:

   ```
                            case yes (n=2)          case no (n=2)
   _______________________________________________________________
   animal - horse (%)       2 (100%)                1 (50%)
   fruit - apple (%)        1 (50%)                 2 (100%)
   ```
2. Perform Odds and Risk ratios of the outcome variable in cases Vs. controls

Note that eventhough all data is avaiable for id 2, it doesnt get included in the analysis because it doesnt have a matched control, therefore it's not a case.

How can I achieve his with SPSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the FUZZY extension command to create the case-control matches, it can create a dataset of the matched pairs.  Otherwise join the selected controls to the case data using MATCH FILES with a TABLE join.  (You can do this even if the cases and controls are in the same dataset.)